# Retrieve file from S3. - Carrierwave Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm implementing Carrierwave with fog storage into my Rails App. The whole purpose of this app is to store pdf articles and have the ability for anyone with access to the app to retrieve them. Right now, I have the functionality of storing the article pdf working great. But, now I need to be able to retrieve the pdf from S3. Is this possible? I noticed in the docs there is a `uploader.retrieve_from_store!("my_file.png")` method. I tried to run this in the console and I got this error `NoMethodError: undefined method retrieve_from_store! for ArticleUploader:Class` Any help with this would be great! I'm just not finding any suitable answers so far. Thanks!

## Article Uploader

```
class ArticleUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :fog

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf)
  end

end
```

## Article Model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :file, ArticleUploader
  validates :title, presence: :true
  validates :publication_date, presence: :true
  validates :source, presence: :true
end
```

Comment: How do you store article pdf? Are you mounting uploader to a column? Please add more info. Ie. uploader class code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it with the methods that carrierwave has, in your case:

```
article = Article.find(1)
article.file.url
```

If you are on development it will output the path for the `file` and if you are on production and using S3, it will output the whole url, `http://s3.amazonaws.com/<vendor>/articles/1/file.pdf` for example.

You can find more information on the official docs:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#activerecord

There is also an old rails cast on that http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads